# XML parsing using Python ElementTree to extract specific data

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an xml file that I need to parse. I vaguely understand python and xml. I'm using ElementTree to parse the document, however just about every reference I've researched online gets me on the right track but I fall short on a particular aspect of my use case. If my xml looks like:

```
<root/>
    <blah>
       <blah/>
    <blah/>
    <blah>
       <blah/>
    <blah/>
    <CheckList>
       <CheckListChild>
           <category1>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Open"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
            <category1/>
            <category2>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Open"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
            <category2/>
            <category3>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Open"/>
            <category3/>
```

I want to write a for loop to iterate over children in the tree, but I *only* care about category1 children with the "status = Open". Every reference ive read including the python documentation leads me to pulling all attributes with status Open, but this causes me to pull category2 and category3's which I dont want. Is there any way to isolate this to just category1 children? I want to eventually append the output to a list but can figure that out once I isolate this output.

I've tried something like but this dosent work:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

report = xmldocument.xml
tree = ET.parse(report)
root = tree.getroot()

cat1findings = []
for item in root.iter('category1'):
    for blah in root.iter(blah):
      if blah.attrib == 'Status="Open"':
        cat1findings.append(output)
```

TIA!

Comment: Explain "doesn't work". What happens, what exactly should happen?

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). XML sample is invalid XML and code is incomplete or contains unknown variables.

Comment: Your sample XML document is useless as an example: it contains numerous syntactical errors, nor does it match the expectations of your code. Show us code and data then run without producing syntax errors, even if they don't yet produce your desired results.

Comment: probably it would be simpler to use `lxml` or maybe `Beautifulsoup`

Comment: better create minimal working code with correct example data so we could simply copy and run it - to see problem and test solutions.

Comment: your code ans XML is one big mess. But I see two problems in code (1) you have to use `item` instead of `root` in `for blah in item.iter('blah'):`, (2) it should be `if blah.attrib['status'] == "Open"`

Comment: noted everyone, thank you for the feedback. Not used to posting questions on stack so will read up on proper posting and putting together real code instead of hastily written out examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `lxml` and `xpath` to find it.

Because `xml` is not complete so I use `lxml.html` instead of `lxml.etree`.

It may have one problem. I uses `C/C++` libraries `libxml2` and `libxslt` which you have to install separately (because it is not Python code) and some people may have problem to do this.

I added some text in tag to show how to get inner text.
I put `xml` directly in code but you can read it with standard `open()`,`read()`
or `lxml.html.parse("data.xml")`

```
text = '''<root/>
    <blah>
       <blah/>
    <blah/>
    <blah>
       <blah/>
    <blah/>
    <CheckList>
       <CheckListChild>
           <category1>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Open">Hello World!</blah>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
            <category1/>
            <category2>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Open"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
            <category2/>
            <category3>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Open"/>
            <category3/>
'''

import lxml.html

soup = lxml.html.fromstring(text)

data = soup.xpath('.//category1/blah[@status="Open"]')

for item in data:
    print('Parent:', item.getparent().tag)
    print('Status:', item.attrib['status'])
    print('RuleTitle:', item.attrib['ruletitle'])  # it needs lower case `ruletitle` instead of `RuleTitle`
    print('Text:', item.text)
    print('XML:', lxml.html.tostring(item))
```

Result:

```
Parent: category1
Status: Open
RuleTitle: description
Text: Hello World!
XML: b'<blah ruletitle="description" status="Open">Hello World!</blah>\n               '
```

---

**EDIT:**

Your code and XML is one big mess.

I see few problems

- XML is not correct file - it has wrong tags (after corrections it works).
- it can't find `getroot()` (but it works without `getroot()`)

and 2 main problems:

- you have to use `item` instead of `root` in `for blah in item.iter('blah'):`,
- it should be `if blah.attrib['status'] == "Open"`

Full working code:

```
text = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <blah>
       <blah/>
    </blah>
    <blah>
       <blah/>
    </blah>
    <CheckList>
       <CheckListChild>
           <category1>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Open">Hello World!</blah>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
            </category1>
            <category2>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Open"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
            </category2>
            <category3>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Open"/>
            </category3>
       </CheckListChild>
    </CheckList>
</root>    
'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

#tree = ET.parse('xmldocument.xml')
tree = ET.fromstring(text)
root = tree#.getroot()

cat1findings = []

for item in root.iter('category1'):
    for blah in item.iter('blah'):
        if blah.attrib['status'] == "Open":
            cat1findings.append(blah.text)
            
print(cat1findings)
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed above, your XML isn't useful for parsing and have numerous syntactical errors. If this is corrected and you are only interested in one single value, you don't need a list. But not clear what you like to reach with this category1 and status open? Use `find()` with the **xpath** instead.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <blah/>
    <CheckList>
       <CheckListChild>
           <category1>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Open"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
            </category1>
            <category2>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Open"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
            </category2>
            <category3>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Closed"/>
               <blah RuleTitle = "description" status = "Open"/>
            </category3>
        </CheckListChild>
    </CheckList>
</root>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

interested_blah = root.find('.//category1/blah[@status="Open"]')
print(interested_blah.tag, interested_blah.attrib)
```

Output:

```
blah {'RuleTitle': 'description', 'status': 'Open'}
```

Comment: thank you for this, xpath seems like a great starting point here, I'll start working on something with this. The xml written out isnt accurate at all It was just something to try and get my point across, noted in the future to provide real proper syntax. definitely makes sense that it'd be useful for help